# What are signals in netbeans C++ debugging

Tags: c++, debugging

Hey guys I'm trying to debug my C++ application (running it produces no errors but also no output) and it gives me a signal caught error at this point.

*'Signal received: ? (Unknown signal)'*

Trying to continue with the debug gives me this message:

*unrecognized or ambiguous flag word \"?\?
     no registers*

What could cause this?
The error occurs on this line:

```
if (input.at(i) == 'I') {
```

input is a string, given it's value by a user input (Roman Numeral)

Which is part of the following code (Converting Roman Numerals to Arabic Numbers):

```
//converting Roman Numerals to Arabic Numbers
int toArabic() {

    //converts input to upper case
    transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::toupper); 

    int last_digit = 0;
    int current_digit = 0;
    int arabic = 0;

    //checks that input matches desired numerals
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++) {
           if (input.at(i) == 'I' ||
                   input.at(i) == 'V' ||
                   input.at(i) == 'X' ||
                   input.at(i) == 'L' ||
                   input.at(i) == 'C' ||
                   input.at(i) == 'D' ||
                   input.at(i) == 'M')  {

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++) {
            //Error occurs below
            if (input.at(i) == 'I') {
                current_digit = 1;
            }

            if (input.at(i) == 'V') {
                current_digit = 5;
            }

            if (input.at(i) == 'X') {
                current_digit = 10;
            }

            if (input.at(i) == 'L') {
                current_digit = 50;
            }

            if (input.at(i) == 'C') {
                current_digit = 100;
            }

            if (input.at(i) == 'D') {
                current_digit = 500;
            }

            if (input.at(i) == 'M') {
                current_digit = 1000;
            }

            if (last_digit < current_digit && last_digit != 0) {
                current_digit -= last_digit;
                arabic -= last_digit;
                arabic += current_digit;
                last_digit = current_digit;
                current_digit = 0;

            } else {
                last_digit = current_digit;
                arabic += current_digit;
                current_digit = 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
               break;
    }
        }
    return arabic;
}
```

Comment: I am having something similar: `Unrecognized or ambiguous flag word: \"?\".` no idea what is that, I think it is related to GDB

Comment: where is `ìnput` defined ? you are probably getting a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in C++ when I was actually reading invalid data which resulted in an Exception being thrown. Seems like NetBeans does not properly show that information when debugging. At least with version 8.1 and cygwin gdb I observed that problem.
Maybe a segmentation fault. Debug and check for NULL or invalid values.